# Replace 0 in dataset by column mean

Tags: r

here is my code so far...
strangly it works for some columns and for some not... any idea whats wrong?

```
for(i in 1:ncol(NASDAQ)){
  NASDAQ[NASDAQ[,i]==0, i] <- mean(NASDAQ[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Best regards

Freddy

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, is one option with `na.aggregate` from `zoo`, which by default takes the `mean` of the column to replace `NA`.  Here, we `replace` the 0 values in the dataset by `NA` and then apply `na.aggregate` directly

```
NASDAQ <- na.aggregate(replace(NASDAQ, NASDAQ == 0, NA))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr) #1.0.0
NASDAQ <- NASDAQ %>%
          mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(., . == 0, mean(., na.rm = TRUE))))
```

If we have a version of `dplyr` that is not recent, use `mutate_all`

```
 NASDAQ %>%
     mutate_all(~ replace(., .== 0, mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```